# Backbone Comparator: Sort by alphabets and get by character

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am using Backbone.pageable to paginate my collection.

```
var myarray = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
url: '/json/file.json',
mode: 'client',
comparator: function (model, charater) { 
    //something here??
    return model;
},
state:{
  sortKey: "name"
  order: "-1"
})
```

I want to write a comparator function which takes a character and gets only those names which starts from alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server modein Pageable(the default), you don't need a comparator, or `sortBy`.

Server mode relies on server fully to provide sorting, and every request will result in the reset of collection. So you just need define `sortKey` in `state` and arrange your server to respond accordingly.

If you are using client side mode, you can define comparator. Note `comparator` accepts String only in Backbone, so if it's a function you need to define `sortKey` instead.